# how to compare two lines, which are inverted respect to space

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have the following output for VPN tunnel status:

```
[root@localhost:~]# setkey -D
82.113.11.226 10.18.1.201
        esp mode=tunnel spi=143937423(0x08944f8f) reqid=0(0x00000000)
        E: 3des-cbc  c114543c 3049e8b8 c033e4ea 07e0054e 3e8ac254 f0dbb7f5
        A: hmac-md5  8461e21b 2318bb9c 352bee1d e24a0a53
        seq=0x00000000 replay=4 flags=0x00000000 state=mature
        created: Jan 28 09:52:41 2013   current: Jan 28 09:56:58 2013
        diff: 257(s)    hard: 3600(s)   soft: 2880(s)
        last: Jan 28 09:52:49 2013      hard: 0(s)      soft: 0(s)
        current: 852(bytes)     hard: 0(bytes)  soft: 0(bytes)
        allocated: 11   hard: 0 soft: 0
        sadb_seq=1 pid=12264 refcnt=0
10.18.1.201 82.113.11.226
        esp mode=tunnel spi=3053715472(0xb6040010) reqid=0(0x00000000)
        E: 3des-cbc  28c87550 a6c9a17b 37ad0b02 03567617 79647aeb 644563d8
        A: hmac-md5  0ef83de9 1b279a16 658eb176 dad37d50
        seq=0x00000000 replay=4 flags=0x00000000 state=mature
        created: Jan 28 09:52:41 2013   current: Jan 28 09:56:58 2013
        diff: 257(s)    hard: 3600(s)   soft: 2880(s)
        last: Jan 28 09:52:41 2013      hard: 0(s)      soft: 0(s)
        current: 1524(bytes)    hard: 0(bytes)  soft: 0(bytes)
        allocated: 19   hard: 0 soft: 0
        sadb_seq=0 pid=12264 ref
```

I want to take lines which only consist ip address and compare if left part of the first line is equal with right part of the second line, which are space's delimited and vise-and-versa. On the first step I made following command:

```
[root@localhost:~]# setkey -D | sed -n '/\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}/p'
82.113.11.226 10.18.1.201
10.18.1.201 82.113.11.226
```

Lines are interested respect to space. Can anybody to advice any awk or sed expression to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier to compare strings using `awk`. Try this:

```
setkey -D | awk 'NR==1 { a=$1; b=$2; next } !/^ / { print ($1==b && $2==a ? "match" : "none") }'
```

On your input, my results are:

```
match
```

Comment: Great decision, that's all that I needed

Answer (score 1):

First bring the ip addresses onto the same line using `tr`, then use `egrep` with backreferences to check if they are the same:

```
$ cat file
10.18.1.201 82.113.11.226
82.113.11.226 10.18.1.201

$ tr '\n' ' ' < file | egrep "^(.*) (.*) \2 \1"
82.113.11.226 10.18.1.201 10.18.1.201 82.113.11.226
```

Comment: thank you man, I have the same idea, but using while read line. So understood what you mean, but @steve do it more convenient for more

Comment: What about the lines in between `grep -v '^ ' file | tr '\n' ' ' | egrep "^([0-9.]+) ([0-9.]+) \2 \1"`

Comment: sorry, but I think it's related with grep from busybox and you variant is not worked for me `[root@localhost:~]# cat 11122222  
82.113.11.226 10.18.1.201  
10.18.1.201 82.113.11.226  
[root@localhost:~]# grep -v '^ ' 11122222  | tr '\n' ' ' | egrep "^([0-9.]+) ([0-9.]+) \2 \1"  
[root@localhost:~]#`

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way would be to simply use `read` and read data into separate variables like this:

```
read -r trash right
read -r left trash
# compare left and right
```